# A question about Pascal triangle

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

There is a number $n \in \mathbb{N}, \ n > 1, n < 2^k$. How to prove this statement:
 $n$ is included into Pascal triangle not more than $2k -2$ times?

Comment: Where does this question come from?

Comment: From the way you phrase your question, you seem to know that this is a true statement. Where does that knowledge come from?

Comment: In addition to the problems with lack of context, this question is cross-posted to MSE.

Comment: similar question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28717/singmasters-conjecture

Comment: The m.se post is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585658/a-question-about-pascal-triangle

Comment: Since the question appears to be an open research problem, I am not sure why this was closed. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Igor Rivin As said above, this question has been posted simultaneously on Math.stackexchange without mentionning the double posting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a result of Singmaster (American Math Monthly, 1971).

Here is his proof ($N(a)$ is the number of times $a$ appears.) This result has since been much improved, see the [wikipedia article on Singmaster's conjecture.](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Singmaster%27s_conjecture)

[image]

To elaborate somewhat, Abbott-Erdos-Hanson show:
[image]
and use this to show the better asymptotic bound. It is not quite clear how to use this to get better bounds for all $t.$

Comment: The proof gives $N(a)\le2+2\log_2a$, and OP wants $N(a)\le2k-2$ when $a<2^k$, which is a little bit stronger (but maybe the improved results in the wikipedia essay give what's needed).

Comment: @GerryMyerson The results in the wikipedia link are asymptotically better, so they definitely do the trick. I did not notice the plus vs minus, *mea culpa.*

Comment: if they're asymptotically better, then they do the trick for $a$ sufficiently large, but not necessarily for all $a$, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson See the edit. It is not clear that one can get the better result for ALL $t$ using this technology.