# Solve $\binom{n}{k}=m$ for $(n,k)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

For an integer $m>0$, put $X(m)=\{(n,k):4\leq 2k\leq n \text{ and } \binom{n}{k}=m\}$.  Is there an efficient method to calculate $X(m)$?  Is there a uniform upper bound for $|X(m)|$?

By calculating $\binom{n}{k}$ for $4\leq 2k\leq n\leq 1000$ I have found that $X(3003)\supseteq\{(14,6),(15,5),(78,2)\}$ and seven other cases where $|X(m)|>1$ but no more than that.

This question arose because I am running an online test for undergraduates in which the correct answer is a certain binomial coefficient.  Frequently they enter a different binomial coefficient and it is useful for the marking logic to determine the corresponding pair $(n,k)$.  In practice this can be done by searching through a fairly small plausible parameter space.  However, the theoretical question seemed like it might be interesting.

One possible ingredient is the following fact which is quite well-known to algebraic topologists: if $p$ is prime and $v_p(n)$ is the $p$-adic valuation of $n$ and $\sigma_p(n)$ is the sum of the base $p$ digits of $n$, then
$$ v_p\binom{n}{k} = \frac{\sigma_p(k)+\sigma_p(n-k)-\sigma_p(n)}{p-1} $$

[UPDATE: The comments give a good answer about upper bounds for $|X(m)|$; but I am still interested in an algorithm for a given $m$.]

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singmaster%27s_conjecture and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28717/singmasters-conjecture

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2857338/573047) at math.stackexchange.

Comment: For a given $m$ you only need to search up to $n=m$ since the rows of Pascal's triangle are strictly unimodal and $\binom{n}{1} = n$. This leads to an algorithm for finding all solutions to $m=\binom{n}{k}$, although not an efficient one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find a solution in logarithmic time by starting with $i=2$, each time searching (with binary search, for example) for the smallest number such that $\binom{n}{i} \geq m$, return $(n, i)$ if it's exactly $m$, and terminate once $\binom{2i}{i} > m$.

For correctness of the early termination, we can see that if $\binom{n}{k} = m$ and $2k \leq n$, we also have $\binom{2k}{k} \leq m$, and since the central binomial coefficients are increasing we won't terminate before $k$.

For the runtime, since the central binomial coefficients grow exponentially, the number of steps must be $O(\log m)$.

Here's an efficient Python implementation, using Newton's method, either directly on the polynomial if $i$ is small (so we need a lot of precision), or on the logarithm if $i$ is large:

````
import math
import gmpy2
import scipy.special


def binom_der(x, i):
    v, d = 1, 0
    for j in range(i):
        v, d = v * (x - j), v + d * (x - j)
    return v, d


def newton(mt, i):
    x = int(gmpy2.root(mt, i) + 1)
    lt = 0
    gt = math.inf
    if x < 1000000:
        mlg = math.log(mt)
        while True:
            fv = math.lgamma(x + 1) - math.lgamma(x - i + 1)
            fd = scipy.special.psi(x + 1) - scipy.special.psi(x - i + 1)
            nx = x - (fv - mlg) / fd
            if abs(nx - x) <= 0.001:
                if abs(nx - round(nx)) <= 0.01:
                    v = round(nx)
                    if math.perm(v, i) == mt:
                        return v
                return None
            x = nx
    while True:
        fv, fd = binom_der(x, i)
        if fv == mt:
            return x
        if fv < mt:
            lt = max(lt, x)
        else:
            gt = min(gt, x)
        if gt - lt <= 1:
            return None
        nx = x + (mt - fv) // fd
        if x == nx:
            return None
        x = nx

def invb(m):
    i = 2
    mt = m
    while math.comb(2 * i, i) <= m:
        mt *= i
        n = newton(mt, i)
        if n:
            assert math.comb(n, i) == m
            return n, i
        i += 1
    return None
```
````

Comment: Is this presuming that we can compute an arbitrary binomial coefficient in constant time? Without that assumption it's not immediately clear to me that this algorithm runs in logarithmic time, because we might spend $\Theta(n)$ or more operations just doing our binomial computations.

Comment: I have implemented this in Maple, starting the search with $n=(i!m)^{1/i}$.  For $m=\binom{103}{40}=\binom{104}{39}\simeq 10^{29}$ it takes about  $0.3$ seconds.  For $m=\binom{713}{273}=\binom{714}{272}\simeq 10^{205}$ it takes about $200$ seconds.  I feel like it should be possible to do better if we initially use Stirling approximations and analytic methods and then refine the answer using exact arithmetic at the end, but my current implementation of that idea is not working correctly.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki all numbers involved have at most $\log m$ digits, so computing the binomial coefficient takes at most $O(i \log^k m)$ time. Note that I'm not claiming an $O(\log m)$ time, just $O(\log^k m)$

Comment: Excellent, that's essentially instantaneous even for $\binom{713}{273}$