For all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, How to find $\min\{ m+k\}$ such that $ \binom{m}{k}=n$?
I asked this question on MSE here.

Most numbers in pascal triangle appear only once (excluding the duplicates in the same row of the Pascal's triangle)  but  certain numbers appear multiple times. For instance, $6$ appears twice as $\binom{4}{2}$ and $\binom{6}{1}$. Here I asked my self What is $\min\{ m+k\}$ such that $ \binom{m}{k}=n$?

Define the sequence $a_n$ as follows: $a_n = \min\{m + k\}$ such that $\binom{m}{k}=n.$
The initial terms of $a_n$ (arranged in $(n,a_n)$) are:

( 2, 3),
( 3, 4),
( 4, 5),
( 5, 6),
( 6, 6),
( 7, 8),
( 8, 9),
( 9, 10),
( 10, 7),
( 11, 12),
( 12, 13),
( 13, 14),
( 14, 15),
( 15, 8),
( 16, 17),
( 17, 18),
( 18, 19),
( 19, 20),
( 20, 9),
( 21, 9),
( 22, 23),
( 23, 24),
( 24, 25),
( 25, 26),
( 26, 27),
( 27, 28),
( 28, 10),
( 29, 30),
( 30, 31),
( 31, 32),
( 32, 33),
( 33, 34),
( 34, 35),
( 35, 10)

(The bold numbers are which has $a_n< n+1$)
These are generated by this code:
import math
print("the input is the maximum number $n$ to check for i.e for all j between 1, n the code gives the min{m+k} such that mCk =n , the output is in the for of $(n , min (m+k : mCk=n)) $")
j=int(input())
for n in range (2,j+1):
    C=[]

    l=0
    for m in range (1, n+1):
        s=0


        k=1
        while k<( math.floor(m/2)+1-l):
            if math.comb(m,k)>n:
                l=l+1
                break
            if math.comb(m,k)==n:
                C.insert(s,m+k )
                s=s+1
                if min(C)<n+1:

                    break
            k=k+1                      
    print(f"({n},{min(C)}), ")                               

Here are some graphs of $(n,a_n)$:




It is easy to see that:
Most n have $a_n =n+1$, The  numbers $n$ with $a_n < n+1$ are of the form $\binom{r}{q}$ where $2 \le  q \le r-2$.
These numbers are precisely the ones that appear more than once in Pascal's triangle (excluding symmetric pairs in the same row of Pascal's triangle ).
The question is: How to find $a_n$ where $n$ has the form $\binom{r}{q}$ where $2 \le  q \le r-2$?

It seems that for such $n$, the minimum $m + k$ occurs when $m$ is minimized (the first occurrence of $n$ in Pascal's triangle) This is true up to  $n=50,000,000,000,000$ . Can this be proven? Another question would be how to find $m , k$ that minimise $m+k$?


Here are the first few $a_n$ where $n$ has the form $\binom{r}{q}$ where $2 \le  q \le r-2$:

6,
7,
8,
9,
9,
10,
10,
11,
12,
13,
11,
14,
12,
15,
12,
16,
17,
13,
13,
19,
20,
14,
21,
22,
14,
15,
24,
15,
25,
26,
16,
27,
28,
15,
29,
17,
30,
31,
32,
18,
16,
33,
16,
34,
35,
19,
36,
37,
38,
39,
20,
40,
17,
41,
42,
17,
21,
43,
44,
45,
18,
46,
22,
47

I tried to look for this sequence on OEIS but this sequence doesn't exist there which might suggest that a closed form is not easy to find.

Here are the first few $a_n$ where $n$ has the form $\binom{r}{q}$ where $2 \le  q \le r-2$ arranged in the form $(n , a_n)$

(6,6),
(10,7),
(15,8),
(20,9),
(21,9),
(28,10),
(35,10),
(36,11),
(45,12),
(55,13),
(56,11),
(66,14),
(70,12),
(78,15),
(84,12),
(91,16),
(105,17),
(120,13),
(126,13),
(136,19),
(153,20),
(165,14),
(171,21),
(190,22),
(210,14),
(220,15),
(231,24),
(252,15),
(253,25),
(276,26),
(286,16),
(300,27),
(325,28),
(330,15),
(351,29),
(364,17),
(378,30),
(406,31),
(435,32),
(455,18),
(462,16),
(465,33),
(495,16),
(496,34),
(528,35),
(560,19),
(561,36),
(595,37),
(630,38),
(666,39),
(680,20),
(703,40),
(715,17),
(741,41),
(780,42),
(792,17),
(816,21),
(820,43),
(861,44),
(903,45),
(924,18),
(946,46),
(969,22),
(990,47)


Define $s_1=6$, $s_{N+1}$ to be the least integer greater than $s_N$ such that $s_{N+1}$ have the form $\binom{r}{q}$ where $2 \le  q \le r-2$
Here are some graphs of $(n, a_{s_n})$:





Closely related OEIS sequence. This is sufficiently irregular that I highly doubt anything resembling a closed form exists.

by Central binomial coefficients we have $a_{\binom{2n}{n}}=3n$

See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457399/solve-binomnk-m-for-n-k and then you can just iterate over all solutions

Shouldn't $2<k<r-2$ really be $2\le k\le r-2$? For example for $n=10$ you get $a_n=7$ because of $10={5 \choose 2}$. And I think the $n$ where $a_n<n+1$ are  https://oeis.org/A006987

Please clarify the question: What does "How to find a_n where ..." mean? Some single one? All up to some limit? All? If we were to write a program, what would be the input and what shall be the output?

@nocomment It is simple, find the closed form for $a_n$ for all $n$.

@pie what qualifies as a closed form?

"Simple"? What a high rep user and PhD student highly doubts even exists? I'm out, have no chance. Still, a question about your program, as I'm not convinced it's correct: For each n, you stop at the first matching (m,k) you find. What's the justification for that? How do you know there can't be another matching pair with smaller sum?

@nocomment I meant understanding the question is simple find the closed form for $a_n$ given $n$, The answer to the question is not, that is why I post it on MO

In your comment you just said "find ... for all n". But in the question, it is "... where $n$ has the form $\binom{r}{k}$ where $2 \le  k \le r-2$". Which one is it? Or how are these two compatible?

@nocomment: "question about your program, as I'm not convinced it's correct: For each n, you stop at the first matching (m,k) you find. What's the justification for that" Well my idea is that the $\binom{b}{j}> binom{a}{j}$ far all $b>a>2$ and $j\le \lfloor a/2\rfloor$ in my code  while k<( math.floor(m/2)+1-l):  line you can see that the loop ofk shorten when $\binom{m}{k}>n$ and that also mean $\binom{m_2}{k}> \binom{m_1}{k}$ for all $m_1>m_2$ in my code which make searching for other values of $\binom{m}{k}=n$ is meaningless

@nocomment as stated in the question: if $n$ doesn't have this form $a_n =n+1$.

Why are you keeping the same k and not  considering k1 and k2 as well? And for example 14C6=15C5. You ignore the latter. Granted, those have the same sum, and I haven't found a case where you'd miss a smaller sum, but how can you rule that out?

@nocomment Ahaa.. you are right for some reason I didn't notice that but for some reason it works!!

If you want to generate data, here's some more efficient code

n=3003=14C6=15C5 is still the only one I found with two matches of equal sum and I haven't found one with a later smaller sum. Checked all n up to n=50,000,000,000,000.

@nocomment This is very interesting I included that in  the question

@nocomment how did you even reach 50,000,000,000,000?

I wanted to say that $\binom{m+1}{k-1} \leq \binom{m}{k}$ so the minimal $m$ must also minimize $m+k$, but that's false for $k$ which is more than $\approx \frac{2}{3+\sqrt 5} m$

Please rephrase the "An interesting observation from @nocomment is that for such n, the minimum m+k occurs when m is minimized". I didn't observe or say or even think that. Btw apparently there are no more n with five or more binomial coefficients until n=10^60, so also none such cases I've been looking for. See Wikipedia and arxiv.

Your $s_n$ is really exactly the OEIS sequence I pointed out earlier, isn't it?

@nocomment Yes it is the same as the OEIS sequence you pointed out earlier.

Btw I wrote an infinite generator for that sequence: Attempt This Online!.

I used a modified version of that to do the check until n=50,000,000,000,000. And then also a modified version of my old script, which is faster (takes ~11 seconds): Attempt This Online!

@DanielWeber The paper
Singmaster's conjecture in the interior of Pascal's triangle by
Kaisa Matomäki, Maksym Radziwiłł, Xuancheng Shao, Terence Tao, Joni Teräväinen https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.03335 proves that there are at most two solutions with $ 2m/ (3 + \sqrt{5} ) \leq k \leq m $ to $\binom{m}{k}=t$ for $m$ sufficiently large. This is not quite enough to show that there is only one solution in the increasing region, unfortunately.
